# Custom bullet, can't adjust Font

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm compiling a document with bullets and want to change the bullet color.

But in *Define New Bullet* tab, the Font button is not available to select.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose a "Picture" to be used your bullet, then the "Font" button will become unavailable.

You need to choose a "Symbol" to be able to control the font it's shown with, or (instead) create a new bullet image in the colour you'd like, and then instruct Word to use that image as the custom bullet.